# Button Control not working with RowCommand Event

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="lbShowGroup" CommandName="View" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Topic") %>'
                            runat="server" Text="View"></asp:Button>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void tblTopics_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "View")
    {
        Response.Redirect("Group.aspx?Topic=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    }
}
```

Debugging doesn't reach the `RowCommand` event, but when I change the button control to `LinkButton`, it works. What's wrong?

Comment: Do you databind your grid on postbacks?

Comment: It works with Linkbutton not with button

Comment: Perhaps because you use the [`postbackurl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.postbackurl.aspx) property to directly redirect from the linkbutton. At least that came to my mind as you've mentioned that a `LinkButton` works.

Comment: if it works with linkbutton, trr setting `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` and see if that makes a difference...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you databind your grid on postbacks?

You must **not** bind your grid on postbacks in `Page_Load`, only when something has changed that causes the `GridView` to reload data(f.e. Sorting,Paging) and only in the appropriate even-handlers.

So wrap the databinding in a `PostBack`-check:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataBindGrid();
    }
}
```

Another possible reason: Have you disabled `ViewState` somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found out that my problem was in the Master Page where `EnableViewState="false"`.

I changed the Master page to use `EnableViewState="True"`.
 And the `rowcommand` event fired as expected.